# Pygame display only returns half the resolution I input

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just starting out learning pygame and every time I create a new surface for example:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
```

It produces a surface that is (800,600) however only about (400,300) of it is a black screen that acts as the surface for my game. The rest of the screen is just dead space and its white. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem incase anyone has a similar issue it was because I did not have pygame 1.9.2pre. I was also getting this error:

Warning once: This application, or a library it
uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of 
QuickDraw and move to Quartz.

Once I downloaded it my screen resolution was fixed and working as it should and that error message also disappeared.